# Change font color of LibreOffice Writer hidden characters symbols

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Is it possible to change the font color of the symbols for hidden characters in Libreoffice Writer? The symbols are paragraph (¶), space (•), tab (→), and so forth. It seems the default font color is a light bluish color.

Comment: Note: These are called non-printing characters. Hidden characters are something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I change the colour of non-printing characters?

At the moment this is not possible without changing the source code and rebuilding LibreOffice Writer.

There is [an open bug request](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80054) to allow the colour to be customised.

> Following the addition of feature
>   https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.3#Light_Blue_for_Non-printing_characters
>   which was a solution to Bug #68071
>
> and after extensive discussion on the Design mailing list
>   http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Light-Blue-for-Non-printing-characters-tp4110478.html
>
> I'm requesting that an option is added to allow the user to manually
>   select any color (from the LO palette or from RGB, whatever is
>   simpler). This would allow people to select a more visible color (or
>   return to the previous black default if they so wish)

...

> My request is that a separate setting is added under Tools > Options >
>   LibreOffice > Appearance > Custom colors> General > Non-printing
>   characters

Source [Bug 80054 - Enhancement request: Add option to allow user to select color of non-printing characters](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80054)

If you want to modify the source code:

> As can be seen in
>   https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/commit/?id=fb99a6b9958815eb1ad27179d252a379ce8b79fd
>   the `NON_PRINTING_CHARACTER_COLOR` is now defined just once in
>   `/sw/source/core/inc/txtfrm.hxx`; with one additional entry in
>   `inftxt.cxx` for `DrawTab`.
>
> So a simple hack for anyone wishing to change the color of NPC and
>   roll their own.

Source [Color of non-printing characters](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/53134/color-of-non-printing-characters/)